# Bash Script with sed Command is working on terminal but not with a php script

Tags: php, bash

When i'm writing the command `./test.sh testvalue` in the Terminal
it is writing "testvalue" in a script with sed.
But when it runs with php `shell_exec('./test.sh testvalue')`
the php script is writing hello on the page (because in bash, I used echo)
but the bash script isn't writing testvalue in the test.txt data.
Why?
I used chmod a+x+r for php and bash?
Please help me!
Thank you!

My PHP:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $out = shell_exec('./test_sed.sh $test');
    echo "$out";
```

?>

My Bash:

```
#!/bin
new_pw=$1
sudo sed -i '/^wpa_passphrase/d'  test.txt
sudo sed -i '$awpa_passphrase='$new_pw test.txt
echo 'hello'
```

Comment: sorry for $test, I'm of course using test, but it also not works!

Comment: Have you try to set explicit path for the files?

Comment: What does `.` mean to your PHP script? Specify the whole path to the script.

Comment: yes and the . is there for run the bash script

Comment: check if php is executing in a different path ... there may be a `test.txt` in your webservers document root e. g.

Comment: Where did the `$test` comes from? I don't see it defined on the PHP script and neither comes from arguments

Comment: Then be careful you are using a variable inside a string with single quotes. A string with single quotes isn't interpreted that can contain variables

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check:

1. on the PHP script you should change the string into double quotes(so it can interpret variables inside)
2. define `$test` variable (it is undefined)
3. on the PHP script you are trying to execute `test_sed.sh` but on the description you have wrote `test.sh`. Check if is the what you mean
4. and last if you have problems with executing the shell script from CLI too then you should check the shebang. If you have this problem you should try `#!/bin/bash`

I hope it helps

Comment: Yeah, that's right but I've got a variable in my script yet. And I've used #! /bin/bash. It Don't works